# Is it possible to remove the controls in picture in picture mode?

Tags: android

I'd like to remove certain or all control buttons from the picture in picture mode.
As per default, there is a maximize, close, and settings button which I would like to remove.

The documentation only shows how to add other actions rather than override or remove default ones.

[Demo Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBHAu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am also having such use case where I need to remove some controls like previous, next and pause/play button. But didn't get solution yet.